# Equation of a peak diagram

Tags: systems-of-equations, relations

May you please help me how can I extract the equation for this diagram?

[This is the diagram (Click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFunE.png)

I know that the right side is `y=2-2x`

Comment: @ThomasShelby It is not the equation for the diagram

Comment: $f(x)=4x$ if $0\le x \le \frac{1}{2}$, $=-4x$ if $\frac{1}{2} \le x \le 1$, I guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f(x) = 4x if x in [0,1/2], = 4 - 4x if x in [1/2,1].